# Cannot retrieve key values with Parse.Query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Beginner programmer here...I am trying to retrieve the value of specific key from a Parse object. I know that I am retrieving the object because certain keys return a value, i.e. createdAt returns the date value associated with it....the key I want the value for is called "task", which has a string value, but keeps returning undefined. My code looks like this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("TestObject");

         query.get("TC8m9X6XUB", {
        success: function(object) {
            console.log(object.task); 
         },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("An error occured :(");
        }
    });
```

if I replace "object.task" with "object.createdAt" it returns a value. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createdAt, objectId are reserver for Parse. So you can directly call them like object.createdAt. However, if you have a column namely task which has string value then you have to get the value via calling object.get("task"). Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: Your welcome DLateef. If your problem solved, please accept the answer. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use [get()](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Object.html#get).

In your case,

```
object.get('task');
```

Test this,

```
var query = new Parse.Query("TestObject");
query.get("TC8m9X6XUB", {
    success: function(object) {
        console.log(object.get('task')); 
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("An error occured!");
    }
});
```

In Parse, createdAt, ID and updatedAt are special fields. Hence, you can retrieve them without get().